# How to view mail through a client?

Tags: 14.04, server, email, mail

I just finished installing the postfix mail server and I was wondering how I can view my mail through a client rather than through command line?

What clients exist for this and which are considered to be best? Also, what are the security risks I should be aware of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's been ages since I used it (and I can't test it throughly because I have a forwarding server, so nothing is in my local mailbox). But:

If your postfix leave your mail in the standard location (`/var/spool/mail/$USER`) you should be able to use the "movemail" account of `thunderbird`: chose *File -> New... -> Other accounts* from the menu, and setup a "Unix movemai" account:

[image: TTB movemail account]

fill it in and follow the instruction. Should work.

Otherwise, install a POP/IMAP server like, for example, [dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/).